# error in jquery.js in IE and mozilla but not chrome

Tags: jquery

Firebug console throws the error:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript
>   argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"  nsresult:
>   "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   http://localhost:30326/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js :: anonymous :: line
>   6570"  data: no]

in IE the error is coming in line 6570 which is given below:

```
if ((computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null))) {
```

The error is "no such interface supported"

I have absolutely no idea about debugging javascript or jquery...

Has anyone seen this error, any ideas why this could happen...

Tx
Arnab

EDIT:
found out something else as well. This is the jquery method..

```
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {   

        getComputedStyle = function (elem, name) {         

      var ret, defaultView, computedStyle;
                name = name.replace(rupper, "-$1").toLowerCase();
                if (!(defaultView = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView))

    {                return undefined;       

        }
                if ((computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null))) {
```

//  **[This is where error gets thrown elem value is ""]**

```
              ret = computedStyle.getPropertyValue(name); 
                            //               **[The value of name is opacity]**

          if (ret === "" && !jQuery.contains(elem.ownerDocument.documentElement, elem)) {         

              ret = jQuery.style(elem, name);         

          }       

        }
                return ret;   

        }; 

      }
```

But I have not been able to find out from which method of mine, this method in jquery is called , anyone know how to find the order in which js scripts are fired in a page

Solution:

```
if (elem.wholeText == " " && name == "opacity") {
                return "1";
            }
      if ((computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null)))
```

Basically added a code above the line 
if ((computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null)))

Thanks to Justin to show the way....

Comment: please post any relevant lines of *your* code. you can use jsfiddle for this.

Comment: tx, will try to find out the func from which jquery is being called and causing ex...

Comment: It happened to me and I put a try-catch around the getComputedStyle call and got this:[NOTE THAT ELEM IS NOT NULL IN curCSS!]
`[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:35973/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js :: getStyles :: line 6927" data: no]
getStyles(elem=undefined)jquery-1.9.1.js (line 6929)
curCSS(elem=Object { element=g.highcharts-series, renderer={...}, attrSetters={...}, more...}, name="Webk...`

Answer (score 5):

IE9 throws "No such interface supported" when running getComputedStyle on a DOM node which can't have styles (such as a text node).  I ran into this when walking the DOM.  So before passing an element into getComputedStyle, check it's node type, like this:

```
if (elem.nodeType === elem.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're trying to get some offset or position off of a hidden element?  It looks like there may be some precedent with this kind of error:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2528

If that's the case, here is a workaround that may help:

https://siderite.dev/blog/jquery-firefox-error-could-not-convert.html

As mentioned above, it would be extremely helpful to get a sample of the code you're trying to use.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem working with highcharts tooltips.  They were choking on this bit of code from jquery 1.9.1:

```
if ( window.getComputedStyle ) {
    getStyles = function( elem ) {
        return window.getComputedStyle( elem, null);
    }
...
```

It stopped throwing errors by adding a check for nodeType being defined, as I noticed it was null for the svgElement that is used in highcharts.

```
getStyles = function( elem ) {
    if ( elem && elem.nodeType ) {
        return window.getComputedStyle (elem, null);
    }
}
```